# Deny the unauthorized user and redirect to login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have an asp.net mvc application. I have administration page to manage users. Have a scenario where admin adds new users and those uses have its own logins. Say admin creates a user 'testuser' and the testuser logs in to the application. Meanwhile admin deletes 'testuser'. The every next click of 'testuser' must redirect to login page. How can this be done? Is this managed through web.config, or whether this can be managed using the Base Controller(All controllers inherit from Base Controller).

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an overload of the `AuthorizeAttribute` class where you'll check the database for every request wheither the user is still allowed to be logged in in the administration page.

I don't know what your requirements are with regards to the amount of users that will use the administration section, but this can become heavy on the database to have an extra database call on every authorized action.